# rdhs::get_datasets() function giving specific error

Tags: r

I am using rdhs package to work with data from DHS. Previously the package was working fine but now when i try to download specific data sets using the function get_datasets() i receive the following error everytime:

`Error in names(filedatatypelist_DHS) <- paste0("filedatatypelist_", qdapRegex::rm_between(filedatatypelist_DHS_line,  :  'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]`

Has anyone else experienced this?